# How to create a menu separated by a bar but first and last item has no bar?

Tags: css, wordpress

How do you achieve this kind of menu:

About | Privacy | Contact | Site Map

... a menu separated by a vertical bar, but the first and last item doesn't have a bar on the left and right sides (as shown in the example)?

The menu items are generated dynamically (used in wordpress), not manually.

thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using list items as the mark-up for your navigation you can display a line between each link by creating the separator as a **background image** on the `li`.

The trick to get it to only appear in between list items is to position the image to the left of the `li`, but not on the first one.  This example uses the *adjacent selector*:

```
#nav li + li {
    background:url('seperator.gif') no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: 10px
}
```

This CSS adds the image to every list item that follows another list item - in other words all of them but the first.

**Alternatively** you can use the CSS `content` property with the `before` pseudo class, instead of an image.  The following code adds a pipe before your navigation links (again using the adjacent selector).

```
#nav li + li a:before {
    content: "|";
}
```

Be aware the content property is not supported in IE6 and IE7, and the adjacent selector is not supported in IE6.

See here for CSS contents and browser compatibility - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: I see, I'll take note of this. But is there any way not to do this using background images? Does the before or after css attribute help? I'm going to use the menu in a wordpress menu, so menu items are generated dynamically.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include this alternative approach, although personally I find using a background image more flexible.

Comment: +1 though `border-right:solid 1px #000` in lieu of `background` in the first CSS declaration can shave off an HTTP request to achieve the same effect if a pipe character or lookalike is all that's needed (without the potential compatibility issues posed by the second method)

Comment: Thanks, the second method works for now. Though the vertical bar is included and "highlighted" when the link is hovered, but the method works well for now. Will explore using background images later.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bar is just a character on the keyboard, so you can type it in between the words.

Comment: Thanks. However, the menu items are generated dynamically (used in wordpress), not manually.

Comment: OK, I've put that info back into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier solution for wordpress!

Just go to Appearance>Menus and add " |" in the end of the Navigation Label for each title of the menu!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is with a CSS class.

In Appearance → Menus:
http://d.pr/i/I9ko+

1. Click Screen Options
2. Check CSS Classes
3. Add a class of “last” to your last menu item
   Then in your style.css, add:

   `#nav li.last span {
     display: none;
   }`